# ArrayList cannot be shown in a list view - android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am developing an application to get nearby gas stations and show them in a list, my problem is to show them in the list i went through many tutorials but could not figure out the problem which is no list appear with data i am sure that the problem in this part but do not know how to solve it, and to make sure that the problem in this i tried to put progress dialog and to dismiss it directly before this part of code.

here is the method to show the array list using adapter i am calling from onPostexecute

```
protected void showItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> placestoList2){

            ListAdapter adapter101 = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placestoList2,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_VICINITY}, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.vicinty });
lv.setAdapter(adapter101);     
        }
```

and this method to get data from list i am getting of places

```
   protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getLocations(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                    HashMap<String, String> mapM = list.get(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> mapM2 = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    String name = mapM.get("place_name");
                    mapM2.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                    String vicinity = mapM.get("vicinity");
                    mapM2.put(vicinity, vicinity);
                    placesListItems.add(mapM2);
                    }
                return placesListItems;
}
```

and the List view in the Layout

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

the other layout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/vicinty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but could not figure out the problem?"  What is your code doing or not doing that you wish to have happen or not happen?

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is custom adapter. Here's how you need to do it. If I am not wrong your data is stored in List>. Change according to your requirement. Here's what you do in your activity or fragment:

```
ListView listView;
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

//Call this when you have data. If you are only updating think of something else
Adapterlist adapter=new Adapterlist(this,getData());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's the custom adapter:

```
public class Adapterlist extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<HashMap<String,String>> list;

public static final String PLACE="place_name";
public static final String VICINITY="vicinty";

public AdapterApplist(Context context, List<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.vicinty = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.vicinty);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    setUI(holder,position);

    return view;
}

private void setUI(ViewHolder holder,int position){
    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(map.get(PLACE));
    holder.vicinty.setText(map.get(VICINITY));
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView vicinty;
}
```

}

Please do more research next time. This can be found all over internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate that, i just tried it but did not get the view too, and i am not high expert in code that is why i am posting a question i did search but did not get to what i need

Comment: log your list.size() in adapter's constructor and make sure the list isn't empty if it's not post your full xml layout..

Comment: i tried to send the size of list in the constructor and make public int getCount() {
    //return list.size();
 return size;
}
but there is nothing appear, and for the second part the list is not empty because i tried something is to draw markers in the map using latlng in the list and this happened i do not know what is missing, does it parsing list between the activity and the class of adapter